# How to open a new page with new data with Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm creating a function that opens an existing html template page of which I want to update the data "passed as argument" from the function itself.

(I'm doing this to avoid hardcoding multiple pages, so to dynamically create a page for the client based upon what he clicks from a menu, not sure is this is the right way to go about it, but this is what I come up with).

Is it possible with Vanilla JavaScript , if so and how?

Here is my code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/tester.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="load('dpdate one', 'update two', 'update three')"> Update </button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the template page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="js/tester.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="one">Not updated</p>
    <p class="two">Not updated</p>
    <p class="three">Not updated</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript function:

```
function load(one, two, three) {
    console.log('Loadin new page with data!');
    window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/newPageTemplate.html'; 
    // window.location.assign('http://127.0.0.1:5500/newPageTemplate.html');
    // window.location.replace('http://127.0.0.1:5500/newPageTemplate.html');
    const dataOne = document.getElementsByClassName('one')[0];
    const dataTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0];
    const dataThree = document.getElementsByClassName('three')[0];
    dataOne.innerText = one;
    dataTwo.innerText = two;
    dataThree.innerText = three;
}
```

When clicking the button it does redirect but it does not update the data.
How to do that?

FYI: If this is achieved what will happen if multiple user click the same at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I found an hacky solution that works however.

I save the data I need into local storage like so:

```
localStorage.one = 'Anything you want to save';
localStorage.two = 'Anything you want to save';
localStorage.three = 'Anything you want to save';
```

This data will persist even after page redirect and can be utilized in a window.onload function like so:

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log(localStorage.one);
  console.log(localStorage.two);
  console.log(localStorage.three);
}
```

This solution works, however before using check as not really sure about security issues or other. Use at your own risk.